# Moving String and Image between Activity Android Application

Tags: java, android, android-activity, image

I've to develop an application that allows user to browse picture and write some information 
about him, all these information will stored in a class with Person name, 
After he presses NextButton the activiy should moves him to another activity with these information in the second activity he'll type another information about him,

well in the 3rd activity I should receive all these info. from ( 1st and 2nd ) activities then, showing it in the 3rd one ,,

---

my Questions are:

1- How can move more than one info. I write a code that moves string and other code to move picture, but I couldn't combine them with each other!

2- How can I insert the information that will be typed in the second activity to the same object of Person Class ??

---

Hope my Questions and my scenario is clear!!

thanks alot

Shomokh =)

-----------------------Updating----------------------------------------

```
// this is for String info
String FullPersonInfo = person1.toString();
Bundle basket = new Bundle();
basket.putString("key", FullPersonInfo);
Intent intent = new Intent(Form_1.this,Form_2.class);
intent.putExtras(basket);
startActivity(intent);

// I'm confusing how can I add image when i try this code it doesn't work

intent.putExtra("URI", selectedImageUri.toString() );
```

Comment: try this http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.in/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html

Comment: ok God willing, ill try it thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in extra information in the intent you are passing in to the next activity and then read the intent using intent.getExtra in the 2nd and 3rd activity. I hope that gives you better idea.

Comment: thanks alot , I did that with Person name but how can I combine his picture in the same extra ??? thanks

Comment: You mean you want to super impose the text onto the image or just pass the 2 information sets to next activity ? If its just to pass, you can pass in both of them separate and later just read both and use the way you want. Let me know, if this confuses you even more

Comment: Refer to the prasanta-paul's blog. Seems very nice.

Answer (score 0):

you can Create `Parcelable` object of your class that content all information whcih u want to move from one activity to another.use `Bundle.putParcelable` and extract all class object in another Activity.

for passing Parcelable custom or complex object between activites see:

[Passing a list of objects between Activities](http://androidideasblog.blogspot.in/2010/02/passing-list-of-objects-between.html)

http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.in/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html

[Android: Passing object from one activity to another](http://bimbim.in/post/2010/09/27/Android-Passing-object-from-one-activity-to-another.aspx)

and as your application requirement but do't pass whole image in bundle just pass a reference path and text to another activity and retrieve image from path

Answer (score 0):

As omkar.ghaisas aluded to above you can pass extras to an Intent. However, you can only pass primitives OR any object which implements the `Parcelable` interface. Passing string is easy enough but the image data is trickier.

I think you have a couple of options:

1. Write the image path to disk and then pass the file location as a
   string using the Extras in the Intent, plus any other strings you
   need, e.g. other metadata
2. Grab the image as a `byte[]` array, create a class which implements
   `Parceleable` and shuffle the `byte[]` around.

I think #1 is probably easier.